# Best/most secure way to connect to SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++

What would be the best way to connect to a SQL server without storing sensitive login information client-side?

Perhaps: CppClient->HTTP+PHP->SQL?

Any better ideas are much appreciated. Links to libraries, pseudo-code, or raw code. Anything is much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: "_Links to libraries, pseudo-code, or raw code. Anything is much appreciated._" 1) Asking for library recommendations is, explicitly, off-topic for SO. Consider reading through [ask], and [help]. 2) SO is not code writing service either.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about what I think your talking about you are saying that you want to know how to have say clients connect from your app to your database? If this is the case you would want to plug into an api. Never give direct access from your app or program to your secure database. There is no safe way to store that locally.

Comment: Yeh that's what I was thinking about in terms of using PHP as an API?

Comment: Sounds fair. Here is an article on connecting api’s https://www.google.com/amp/s/techbeacon.com/app-nirvana-when-internet-things-meets-api-economy%3famp

Comment: I have not gotten there yet but will be moving on to that soon enough. But that article seems like it can get you started at the very least. Also just Google connecting c# app(I love c#) or c++ app to PHP api.. there are a million articles.

Comment: I'll have a good read of that! Thanks man, haven't been able to find anything on it :)

Comment: No problem. Anytime. If tryout question has been answered just mark it as answered. Have a great night.